# XmlSerializer exception: You must add a reference to assembly netstandard

Tags: .net, mstest, .net-standard, .net-framework-version

I'm working on a solution that has a mixture of the following target frameworks:

- .Net Framework 4.7.2
- .Net 6.0
- .Net Standard 2.0

(*Note: None of our projects target a Framework version lower than 4.7.2*).

I have been gradually upgrading some library projects from 4.7.2 to Standard 2.0, as well as some frontend projects from 4.7.2 to 6.0. After having upgraded several projects already, some of our unit tests are failing, all caused by a singular line of code:

`var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(BusinessClass));`

The `XmlSerializer` class belongs to the `System.Xml.Serialization` namespace.
The `BusinessClass` class exists within a .Net Standard 2.0 library project.

The project running these tests is a .Net Framework 4.7.2 MSTest project.

The full exception is:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to generate a temporary class (result=1).
error CS0012: The type 'System.Object' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'.
error CS0012: The type 'System.Enum' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'.
```

It causes multiple test failures but all of them are caused by this single reference to `XmlSerializer`.

I have taken the following steps to try and solve the issue, to no avail:

- I have tried referencing the `NETStandard.Library` nuget package in the test project.
- Under the properties of the `netstandard` reference, I have set `Copy Local` to `True`, and have confirmed that the `netstandard.dll` appears in the `bin` folder.
- I have added the following to the `csproj` file for the test project:

  ```
  <Reference Include="netstandard">
      <Private>True</Private>
  </Reference>
  ```
- I have added a `bindingRedirect` in the `app.config` like so:

  ```
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="netstandard" publicKeyToken="cc7b13ffcd2ddd51" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.3.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  ```
- I have reversed the `bindingRedirect` to force a downgrade to `2.0.0.0`.
- I have referenced the `System.Xml.XmlSerializer` nuget package to the MSTest project.
- I have referenced the `System.Xml.XmlSerializer` nuget package to the library containing the `BusinessClass`.

None of the above steps have fixed the issue. I am starting to feel as if the relation to `netstandard` is symptomatic, rather than the cause.

Unfortunately I am out of ideas. What other approaches could I take to debug the issue further?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it turns out that if you use the `XmlSerializer` in a .Net Standard or .Net Core project, you'll get this exception. However the message is very misleading, and the fix has nothing to do with adding a reference to `netstandard` at all.

The fix was actually remarkably simple: I added a Nuget reference to `Microsoft.XmlSerializer.Generator` and it suddenly worked. This package is required at runtime for using the `XmlSerializer` in a .Net Standard or .Net Core context.

Microsoft article regarding this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/core/additional-tools/xml-serializer-generator

Answer (score 0):

If you have control over netstandard project - make it multitargeting to resolve the issue

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFrameworks>netstandard2.0;net471</TargetFrameworks>
</PropertyGroup>
```

The accepted solution didn't help me. I have mix of .Net 4.7.1 and netstandard 2.0 projects - and serialization of mixed classes from both fails with the mentioned error.
After long investigations and unlucky workarounds I've found the thread disclosing root-causes. Microsoft closed it as "won't fix, use multitargeting"
https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/21373